# crystal reports 11 recognize a new sp parameter

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

Using CR 11 and SQL server 2008.

I have added a new parameter to my stored procedure and while crystal recognizes this and give me the appropriate error that a parameter is missing, I can't find anywhere to "correct" this.... other than creating a whole new report

please tell me I'm having a brain fart!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Reports datasource definition needs to be refreshed so that the new parameter will be defined within the report as well. This is done through the menu **Database**->**Verify Database**. The parameter entry window will popup to ask for the value to use for the new parameter.